# Doing complex loops in Python lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of strings such as this one:

```
   subject = ['HYB option 1Y10Y STY L op in COP 4 23bps at 2 12bps (hu)',
               'HYB option 1Y10Y SOP Linked op in CHY 0 045% at 0 065%',
               'HYB option Lip 3M10Y SPX Linked op in BRR 0 00bp at +0 25bp',
               'HYB option 2Y15Y NFU Linked op in JPY 0 0498% at 0 0975% (765)',               
               'HYB option 1Y10Y SxX Lked op in USD 5 75bps at 2 34bps',
               'THYB optionSp 9M10Y SX5E Led op in COP 0 065%',
               'HYB option 1Y5Y DEE Likd op in EUR 23bp at 1 76bp (ba3)']
```

I am trying to find a way of looping over this list and doing a replacement and a multiplication operation.

More specifically, how I can do a loop where, when I have a number followed by `bps` or `bp`, I do a multiplication by 100 and replace `bps` or `bp` by `%`.

I already tried to use different looping approaches but none of them is working. What is happening is that when I do the multiplication I can't isolate the ones with `bp` or `bps` and it applies multiplication to the one with `%` as well.

Comment: If your just learning you should go for Python 3 which is the latest version

Comment: Please update your question with code that you have tried, even if it produces the wrong results.

Comment: @Simon, he is perhaps stucke with python 2.7.

Please provide the expected result to be clearer.

Comment: Please show use the "different logics" that you used but did not work.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that is based on [regular expressions with a callback function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> import re
>>> for s in subject:
...   print(re.sub(r"(\d)bps?", lambda m: "%d%%" % (int(m.group(1))*100), s))
... 
HYB option 1Y10Y STY L op in COP 4 2300% at 2 1200% (hu)
HYB option 1Y10Y SOP Linked op in CHY 0 045% at 0 065%
HYB option Lip 3M10Y SPX Linked op in BRR 0 0% at +0 2500%
HYB option 2Y15Y NFU Linked op in JPY 0 0498% at 0 0975% (765)
HYB option 1Y10Y SxX Lked op in USD 5 7500% at 2 3400%
THYB optionSp 9M10Y SX5E Led op in COP 0 065%
HYB option 1Y5Y DEE Likd op in EUR 2300% at 1 7600% (ba3)
```

A brief explanation: `re.sub()` takes a regular expression and whenever there's a match (`\d` = any number), it is sent to a callback function (here: a lambda that does the job: convert to int, multiply by 100, add percent sign). The match is then replaced by the string returned by the callback function.

So every time there's a number followed by `bp` or `bps` (the question mark makes `s` optional), the number is passed to a function that returns a string `number*100%`. The for loop iterates over strings in your list and applies `re.sub()` to each element.